# How to blacklist words in a HTML form?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering how I am able to blacklist certain words from being entered in my form. Specifically, the username field. I'm not sure if I need access to the PHP/JS files, but I have limited access to those.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username" class="control-label">{{ lang('signup.username') }}</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" value="{{ data['login'] }}" name="RegistrationForm[login]" placeholder="Enter username">'===
</div>
{% if name_fields %}
```

```
<script>

function is_banned_name($data) {
           $banned_names = array(
               'socialwizards', 'socialwizard', 'bulkfollow', 'bulkfollows'
           );


           foreach($banned_names as $banned_name) {

               $pattern = '/('.$banned_name.')/';

               $match = preg_match($pattern,$data);

               if($match) {

                   return true;

               }

           }

           return false;
       }

  if(is_banned_name($_POST['username'])) {
                  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger {% if site['rtl'] %} rtl-alert {% endif %}">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    {{ errorMessage }}
</div>
}
</script
```

(Added this to the end of my form)

Comment: We don't work for money on this site but thanks

Comment: You can add blacklisted usernames in a database and whenever the post comes you can check if there is a blacklisted word

Comment: You could do this with JavaScript but it's quite easy for someone determined to disable that it they want to. Better to do it server-side with PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with PHP using javascript is not secure as user can manipulated or disable JavaScript.

```
function is_banned_name($data) {
           $banned_names = array(
               'admin', 'test', 'user', 'fake', 'hack', 'error'
           );


           foreach($banned_names as $banned_name) {

               $pattern = '/('.$banned_name.')/';

               $match = preg_match($pattern,$data);

               if($match) {

                   return true;

               }

           }

           return false;
       }
```

Then you can say

```
if(is_banned_name($_POST['username'])) {
 // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I am having a little trouble adding this to my form (I'm a noob still learning haha), what would I need to modify for this to work? (added to OP)

Comment: You add it to your PHP code, do you program in PHP?

Comment: Nope, I only have access to the 'twig' files, so the majority of it is HTML but there are some scripts there. I have limited access to the backend

Comment: addinng `preg_quote` when making regex to test for banned name would be better

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript but its not advisable. The code below is an example of how JavaScript code will do it. The code will return true if the name consist of the banned names.

````
function is_banned_name(str) { 
var banned_names = ['admin', 'hacker', 'test', 'user', 'free']; banned_names.forEach(element => { 
if(str.match(element)) { return true; } 
}); 
} ```
````